# Print logger.Debug statements in docker logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to instrument the flow of a program, which runs within a docker container. I am defining the docker containers from the docker-compose files and running the following command to start the containers:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Statements of the following format are getting printed on when I run the command `docker logs CONTAINER_ID --follow`:

```
logger.Info("Starting server")
```

I also want to print all the statements of the formats:

```
logger.Debug("Executing this command")
logger.Panic("Quitting")
```

Kindly suggest the correct way to debug and print all logger statements.

Comment: What program are you running inside the container? `docker logs` only shows the stdout and stderr from the process running inside. You need to configure your program to print debug logs as well as information logs. Depending on the software you're using it culd be a environment variable, configuration entry, logging framework, web admin ui, ...

Comment: Program is in Go language

Comment: Go seems to have multiple logging provider. For example [stdlog](https://godoc.org/github.com/alexcesaro/log/stdlog) where you could set `-log` switch like `-log=debug`. Since this depends on the module, you need to find out which module you're using in case of a self written program. Otherwise look at the documentation. It's not possible to give you detailled instructions without knowing what exactly software you're using.